# Power Automate Desktop x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm attempting to send an API request in Power Automate Desktop. I've tested it in Postman, and it works flawlessly. However, when I replicate the same request in Power Automate, I encounter an error message stating 'invalid request.' I suspect the issue might be related to the encoding of the body as x-www-form-urlencoded. I've tried formatting my body data as e.g.'token:Token&client_secret:secret,' but the error persists. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows how to properly handle x-www-form-urlencoded body data in Power Automate?

**Working Postman**
[image: Working in Postman]

**Power Automate Desktop**
[image: Power Automate Desktop]

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like cloud Power Automate, it may be expecting a JSON payload in the body instead of simple "key=value".

In the example below, I create a JSON payload using the PARSE JSON action in Power Automate, then I add the body of that to the HTTP request BODY.

[image]